# Yandex Maps API force balloon panel at bottom of maps

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps, yandex-api

Yandex has the following example for displaying a balloon as a panel along the bottom of the map, but this only works when the viewport is small enough. Modern smartphones have higher resolution and this forces the balloon to be floating in an unpredicatble location.

Is there a way to force the balloon to be a panel along the bottom even at larger screen sizes?

Yandex Example: https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon
[image]